# Object attributes to same-length representation for faster reading

Tags: java

I want to convert the attributes of my 'person' object to a representation where I can write lines to a file representing each person. A number of machines need to concurrently read their allocated chunk of the file and so I am moving from lines of character encoded text to list of bytes instead. I hope that by each person's representation being the **same length** I don't have to read every character and the reading application can 'jump' to where it needs to start reading.

This is what I've written so far, to take the attributes of the object and put them into a form where the length will always be the same. Can I do it like this? I modified this code from when I did the same but for creating string representations and concatenating these strings.

I'm also not sure if my method of converting the booleans is necessary/correct.

```
byte[] person = new byte[8];
person[0] = Integer.byteValue(age);
if (gender.equals('m')) {person[1] = Integer.byteValue(1);}
else {person[1] = Integer.byteValue(0);}
person[2] = Integer.byteValue(children);
person[3] = Integer.byteValue(goodHealth? 1:0);
person[4] = Integer.byteValue(cars);
person[5] = Integer.byteValue(avgWeekShopping);
person[6] = Integer.byteValue(salary);
person[7] = Integer.byteValue(smoker? 1:0);
```

Hope it can be understood what I'm trying to achieve. Cheers.

Comment: Is there any reason they all have to be in the same file? Or for that matter, why not just put it in a database?

Comment: i will be using a distributed storage approach eventually, however I first need to assume that I am stuck with a single very large file on a single machine. Cheers

Comment: seeing as how the data isn't yet written (because you're figuring out how to do so in this post) why would you not be able to use a database? It already has these problems solved. Any decent database (mysql, hell even derby) can handle that problem.

Comment: It's a proof-of-concept where the data comes in that form. I will later be making recommendations for storing differently in the first place but for now I need to simulate using one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elaborating on @trashgod's answer, your problem can be split into two parts; encoding the data and making sure that the encoded data can be represented in records of the same length.

The obvious way to encode the data is as follows:

```
byte[] bytes;
try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(/* size hint */);
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
    dos.writeInt(age);
    dos.writeBoolean(gender.equals('m'));
    dos.writeInt(children);
    dos.writeBoolean(goodHealth);
    dos.writeInt(cars);
    dos.writeInt(avgWeekShopping);
    dos.writeInt(salary);
    dos.writeBoolean(smoker);
    bytes = baos.toByteArray();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new AssertionError("this can't happen", ex);
}
```

If you have a fixed number of fields with primitive types, then the encoded byte arrays will have a fixed sized.

If you have variable numbers of fields, or variable length strings, then the size of the encoded byte array will be variable.  To deal with this, you will need to choose some maximum record size, and pad all of the encoded byte arrays to that size.

---

Having said that, the chances are that you'll get a better overall result if you use a database rather than trying to do file management yourself.  This is especially so if your application needs to search the records.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Number of fields will always be as above. The compiler doesn't like the getBytes method. Any ideas why? Thanks

Comment: [`toByteArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html#toByteArray%28%29)?

Comment: this seems to be the right method. i had to catch I/O exception, but still won't compile as cannot find symbol 'bytes' when i try to return it.

Comment: @bashcrufter: Declare `bytes` outside the `try…catch` block.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at [`DataOutputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) and [`DataInputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html), instead.

As @glowcoder suggests, a database can arbitrate among concurrent users and it's more scalable. [H2 Database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) is a good choice.