# Convert object attributes to always-same-length string

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Object attributes to same-length representation for faster reading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5783393/object-attributes-to-same-length-representation-for-faster-reading)

I want to write my objects to a file where each object's representation is the same length, so I can jump to a section of the file to read without having to read the whole file.

This is necessary as the file will be read by many VMs and will be TBs in size. What's the best way of doing this? I've tried putting them in an array of ints to try to achieve this, but it seems this step must be unnecessary. I am passing each object back one at a time to be written by a different writer object. Cheers

```
// Convert Person attributes to integers and put in an array
int[] person = new int[8];
person[0] = age;
if (gender.equals("m")) {person[1] = 1;}
else {person[1] = 0;}
person[2] = children;
person[3] = goodHealth? 1:0;
person[4] = cars;
person[5] = avgWeekShopping;
person[6] = salary;
person[7] = smoker? 1:0;

return person;
```

Comment: would you post a code sample?

Comment: Are you writing arbitrary objects? Or are they all different instances of some class hierarchy? Also, what is the purpose of writing them all into 1 file? And what do you mean different VMs will be reading the file?

Comment: They are all instances of the same class. I am simulating an e-social science system that queries one very large virtual population dataset. I want worker VMs to read their allocated chunk from the one file. I know there will be an I/O bottleneck. I'll post some code now. Thanks

Comment: post it on the original question, this one will probably be closed soon.  Note - posting a nearly identical question to one you posted earlier is likely to result in swift closure.

Answer (score 1):

It's faster if you write your values to a byte array. This can be written directly to any output stream. And you can save some space, like encoding the smoker flag in a single byte instead.

So you'd need to static methods, one that takes a bean and return a `byte[]`, another one that takes a `byte[]` and creates a new bean. All arrays are equal size and you can easily calculate the offsets of individual datasets without the need of an extra index file.